# Ionic 3: ion-list not showing inside ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-list, ion-item

I'm working in ionic v3. I'm trying to add ion-list in ion-item but its not showing in browser.

Moreover it's giving me `<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->` message in `element section`

here's my code:

```
<ion-item margin-bottom class="bond set-height" (click)="toggleToSingle()">
  <ion-label>Add Single Bond</ion-label>
  <ion-list margin-bottom no-lines class="bond set-inner-height inner-block">
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label>Bond Type</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-option value="100">100</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="200">200</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="750">750</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="1500">1500</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="7500">7500</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="15000">15000</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="40000">40000</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="40000Pre">40000 premium</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label floating>Add here</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-item>
```

In element section

[image]

And in UI:

[image]

The highlighted area is where ion-list is added but not showing anything.

Any help?

Comment: Try to check if you don't have something with styles, maybe `overflow: hidden` or something

Comment: @igor_c  deleted my css as a whole but didin't work. Any other solution?

Comment: @igor_c can u guide me what's this message for ``<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->``?